# How to use xpath to determine which child element we are selecting?

Tags: java, xml, selenium, xpath, nodes

For example if we have an xml as follows:

```
<tr>
 <th>LION</th>
 <th>TIGER</th>
 <th>CHEETAH</th>
 <th>GIRAFFE</th>
 <th>BEAR</th>
</tr>
```

and I wanted to select the xpath element for GIRAFFE... how would (using xpath) I be able to tell which  element under  the GIRAFFE element is? Obviously, by looking at the xml, it is //tr/th[4] .... but is there a way I can use xpath to determine that it is the 4th  element under ??

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just use `//th[.='GIRAFFE']` to select the element?

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what you're asking, but perhaps one of these XPaths will help...

---

This XPath expression,

```
count(/tr/th[.="GIRAFFE"]/preceding-sibling::th)+1
```

will evaluate to

```
4
```

indicating that the GIRAFFE `th` element is the 4th `th` sibling element.

---

This XPath,

```
/tr/th[.="GIRAFFE"]
```

will select the GIRAFFE `th` by virtue of its contents.

---

This XPath,

```
/tr/th[.="CHEETAH"]/following-sibling::th[1]
```

will select the GIRAFFE `th` by virtue of its position after the CHEETAH `th`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select column element by header text in rows and use it in Selenium, here some examples:

**Example of HTML:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>LION</th>
            <th>TIGER</th>
            <th>CHEETAH</th>
            <th>GIRAFFE</th>
            <th>BEAR</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**XPATH for Selenium usage:**

```
//table/tbody/tr/td[count(//table//th[.="GIRAFFE"]/preceding::th)+1]
```

**Selenium Java usage example:**

```
String animalName = "GIRAFFE";

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[count(//table//th[.='" + animalName + "']/preceding::th)+1]"));

WebElement animalElementFromRow1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[count(//table//th[.='" + animalName + "']/preceding::th)+1]"));
WebElement animalElementFromRow2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[count(//table//th[.='" + animalName + "']/preceding::th)+1]"));
```